# Time picker format in Windows Phone

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have in XAML code

```
<toolkit:TimePicker ValueStringFormat="{}{0:H:m:ss}" Foreground="Black" BorderBrush="Black"/>
```

And I would like to select time in format "Hours, Minutes, Seconds" but now I can choose time like "6.22 AM". How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

The default is `{}{0:t}` for the ShortTimePattern aka "6:22AM" as you see. To add seconds easily, just make it the LongTimePattern just by capitalizing the "T" in the same string which gives you `{}{0:T}` like;

`ValueStringFormat="{}{0:T}"`

and you're done, nice and easy...

Hope this helps, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

AM/PM designator is "tt"

The short from A/P is "t"

[see](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
<toolkit:TimePicker ValueStringFormat="{}{0:h:m:ss tt}" Foreground="Black" BorderBrush="Black"/>
```

Or without the seconds:

```
<toolkit:TimePicker ValueStringFormat="{}{0:h:m tt}" Foreground="Black" BorderBrush="Black"/>
```